# AWS FIFO queues subscription with SNS: passing message group id

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, fifo

In my application all the microservices are currently communicating via AWS FIFO queues.

I am currently trying to make all those queues subscribing an SNS topic with some filtering condition.

In the recent past (until March) the AWS documentation used to mention some compatibility issue with SNS. However, today this mention has been removed from the doc:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html#FIFO-compatibility

My question is how to set up my SNS to pass one SNS message attribute as FIFO SQS message group id.

Do you have any clue/hint?

Thanks

**Update:**

As I mentioned in the original question, FIFO queues SNS subscription has been recently supported according to the doc (see above) and to the FAQ (see below):

> Q: With which AWS or external services are Amazon SQS FIFO queues
>   compatible?
>
> Some AWS or external services that send notifications to Amazon SQS
>   might not be compatible with FIFO queues, despite allowing you to set
>   a FIFO queue as a target.
>
> The following features of AWS services aren't currently compatible
>   with FIFO queues:
>
> Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks AWS IoT Rule Actions AWS Lambda Dead
>   Letter Queues
>
> For information about compatibility of other services with FIFO
>   queues, see your service documentation.

https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/?nc1=f_ls

If you just Google it, you will find several articles and forum claiming that this did not work until ~6 months ago.

Comment: This feature is now supported https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-sns-fifo-first-in-first-out-pub-sub-messaging/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the AWS article [Tutorial: Subscribing an Amazon SQS Queue to an Amazon SNS Topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-subscribe-queue-sns-topic.html) see the following:

> **Note:**
>
> Amazon SNS isn't currently compatible with FIFO queues.

Also see the AWS Forum post [FIFO queue subscribes to a SNS topic](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246962).

Comment: Thanks @dmulter Actually until this spring it was not supported and this was reported in the AWS FIFO queues docs. In my question I put the link to the current doc and it seems to be supported now.

Comment: My bad. I contacted AWS and actually it seems that FIFO queue are not going to be able to subscribe SNS topics at least until the end of year

Comment: almost 2 years later, they still are not.

Comment: It is supported now https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-sns-fifo-first-in-first-out-pub-sub-messaging/

Answer (score 3):

We’ve just released Amazon SNS FIFO topics. This should be helpful for your use case. But you can’t automatically turn a message attribute into a message group ID. You have to set both attributes independently. Check it out!

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-sns-introduces-fifo-topics-with-strict-ordering-and-deduplication-of-messages/